# Jump-Diffusion Process: How to calculate the expectation of integral of S(t)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Having a jump-diffuion process $S(t)$ and the transition density $f_{dS(t)}(x)$. 
How can I calculate the Expectation of the integral of $S(t)$ between two instants $t_0$ and $t_1$? $S(t_0)$ is considered to be known. 
Can we say that the Expectation of Integral $S(t)$ is equal to the Integral of the Expectation of $S(t)$?
Note : I need to find the Expectation of the cumulative quantities of $S(t)$ between $t_0$ and $t_1$ knowing the value $S(t_0)$. 
Do not confuse with the expectation of the Integral of $dS(t)$ which is the expectation of $S(t)$ at time $t$. 
Thank you.

Comment: @Jouda Ghamlouch : The full meaning of the transition density $f_{dS(t)}$ is not clear in your post, could you clarify the formal definition ? For your Integral/Expectation exchange it is generally Fubini's theorem which is at stake. Best regards

Comment: $f_{dS(t)}(x)=Prob(dS(t)=x)$ and it is a function of $dt$.
am not sure about Fubini's Theorem. any other suggestions?
Thank you,

Comment: @ Houda : $Prob(dS(t)=x)$ doens't mean anything (at least to any formalism I know of), could you elaborate further until I can get it right ? Best regards

Comment: yes am sorry, 
It is simply the probability density function of $dS(t)$ and it is a function of $dt$.  
Consider an example where $S(t)=W(t)$ (a Wiener process) $f_{dS(t)}(x)$ is equal to the probability density of the normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2=dt$.